# NodeJS and MySQL Getting 500 error after first query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have declared `mysql`, and my connection in `app.js` like so:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.168.1.75',
    user: 'dev',
    password: 'devaccount',
    database: 'PugIt'
});

app.set('connection', connection);
```

And in my `User.js` for registration I have:

```
router.route('/register/steam/finish')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.render('user/register_steam');
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var connection = req.app.get('connection');
        connection.connect();

        // Look For Users
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM Users", function(err, rows, fields) {
            console.log('We Found Something!');
        });

        connection.end();
    });
```

When the page first loads and I hit register, it works fine, but if I hit the button a second time I get a `500` error on my server.

But if I manually declare `var connection` inside each `route` file, this does not happen.

How come I cannot use `req.app.get` with MySQL, I used this method when I used to use `MongoDB` which worked great that way I had one main config in app.js I could alter to change in all route files if I needed. Not sure why I'm getting a `500` error on second `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `connection.connect()` and `connection.end()` on every `POST` request is causing problems. Drop those two lines and you should be good to go. This way the connection is only established once and all requests can re-use the same connection without constantly trying to tear it down and bring it back up again.

You can also [create a pool of mysql connections](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) if you find yourself needing greater concurrency with your database queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to MySQL, I thought it was a security issue to leave the connection open after each query